# interconnect/it Search Replace DB AJAX Error, MySQL - Resolved for use case, but could not locate table problem causing error

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I've been using the *interconnect/it Search Replace DB* tool for years to do effective mass search and replace on MySQL databases. Today I was presented an error that I had never encountered. I am presenting is a work-around as I would call it, but it did seem to resolve the problem for my specific use case.

Script Version: *Search Replace DB v 4.1.1*

Data for replacement, simple: *data1* change to *data2*

Error presented:

> "The script encountered an error while running an AJAX request. If you
> are using your hosts file to map a domain try browsing via the IP
> address directly. If you are still running into problems we recommend
> trying the CLI script bundled with this package. See the README for
> details."

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps and use-case resolution:

(1) Entered the data for replacement in Search and Replace
(2) Connected the database, also tested connection with script option
(3) *Which Tables*, selected 'all tables'
(4) 'Do a safe test run" clicked

All seems OK, until the error was thrown!

The next thing I noticed as that not all of the tables had processed, this was a bit tricky because it was the near last table, so it appears a full table list had been displayed.

Naturally, I then compared the list to the actual database directly. The script ended at a specific table (near the end of all tables)!

(5) So I went back to the *Which Tables* option and chose *Selected Tables*, then selected all the tables, with exception to the next table after the last table that processed successfully. This allowed the script to continue successfully.

The table throwing errors was Wordpress *usermeta*

If you have any idea why this specific table would throw *Search Replace DB v 4.1.1* I welcome any suggestions. I understand this could be specific to the data I have in that table, so might not be a general solution.

Shout out to kalico1 of github for helping with data that verified my use case solution!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is an issue. Changes in selected tables does not solve the problem.

**Workaround** for this problem is using the command line tool:

For example, for wordpress, the below is relevant.

```
php srdb.cli.php -h localhost -n your_db -u your_user -p "your\ pw" --search "http://oldsubdomain.domain.com" --replace "http://newsubdomain.domain.com" --verbose true --dry-run
```

Remember, to run this for "https" as well.
Also run for the cPanel username change.

NOTE:

- Make sure your PHP is 7.3 in WHM/cpanel
- in your password, any special characters need to be uncommented with a ""
- if you get: "#1406 - Data too long for column...", increase the varchar limit of the column and retry the operation... it usually happens when you are over the limit with characters in this column (phpMyAdmin > Structure > column)